# MySQL: Get unique values across multiple columns in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

If my table looks like this:

```
id | colA   | colB | colC
===========================
1  | red    | blue | yellow
2  | orange | red  | red
3  | orange | blue | cyan
```

What SELECT query do I run such that the results returned are:

**blue, cyan, orange, red, yellow**

Basically, I want to extract a collective list of distinct values across multiple columns and return them in alphabetical order.

I am not concerned with performance optimization, because the results are being parsed to an XML file that will serve as a cache (database is hardly updated). So even a dirty solution would be fine.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8):

```
(SELECT DISTINCT colA AS color FROM table) UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT colB AS color FROM table) UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT colC AS color FROM table)
ORDER BY color
```

Comment: Using DISTINCT is optional, UNION returns distinct rows only.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it the normal way:

```
create table new_tbl(col varchar(50));


insert into new_tbl(col)
select cola from tbl
union
select colb from tbl
union
select colc from tbl
```

Then sort:

```
select col from new_tbl order by col
```

Or if you don't want staging table, just do:

```
select cola as col from tbl
union
select colb from tbl
union
select colc from tbl
order by col
```

**Note:** UNION automatically remove all duplicates, if you want to include duplicates, change the **UNION** to **UNION ALL**

Comment: UNION only removes duplicates shared between the unioned tables. If either of the tables includes duplicates unique to its own sub-select, those duplicates won't be removed, you need SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY to do that.

Comment: Also not 100% sure, but I think that your ORDER BY col only applies to the last select, not the whole unioned result-set. You should use parenthesis around the select statements to clarify the purpose.

Comment: reko_t: on the contrary, each of those select, the duplicate in each of them are also removed across all of them

Comment: Ah, it seems that's the case, just tried it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: reko_t: regarding ORDER BY.  i've been programming with SQL for long, i've used MySQL, SQL Server, Postgresql.  the ORDER BY applies on the whole UNIONed set