# MySQL - distinct values from two columns

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a table with multiple columns from which I need to get unique values from two of them.

The table looks something like this

```
msgid    sender    receiver  payload
1        service1  service2  xxx
2        service1  service3  xxx
3        service2  service3  xxx
...
```

The desired output should be: **service1, service2, service3** (distinct values from columns sender and receiver)

I found many different approaches on how to do this and chose using UNION like this:

```
String query = "(SELECT sender AS service FROM messages) UNION " +
        "(SELECT receiver AS service FROM messages) ORDER BY service";
```

I tried also

```
String query = "(SELECT DISTINCT sender AS service FROM messages) UNION " +
        "(SELECT DISTINCT receiver AS service FROM messages) ORDER BY service";
```

which should produce the same since UNION already returns unique values. However, I am getting mysql exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'sender' not found.
```

But column sender exists! When I run

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM messages";
```

everything works just fine. Could you tell me, please, what am I doing wrong? I tried to use similar statement as [this post suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800980/mysql-get-unique-values-across-multiple-columns-in-alphabetical-order). Thanks!

EDIT: this is the EXACT query I am using right now:

```
String query = "SELECT sender AS service FROM messages UNION SELECT receiver AS service FROM messages ORDER BY service";
```

This query should work as mentioned in the comments. However, I still get the exception. Why so? Thanks for troubleshooting...

My mysql version is 5.6.

EDIT2: I had no idea that the problem could be with JDBC and not my statement. I apologiye for not providing this information in my question...

Comment: yes `union` is to get distinct value then why u r using `distinct`..

Comment: what is the exact query that throws the sql exception ?

Comment: as I pointed out in my question, I have tried both statements and they both produce the same exeption...

Comment: That's weird, the query is syntactically correct.

Comment: @Smajl ok , a guess in the dark is when you retrieve the data you use "sender" and not "service" that could explain why the first 2 queries work and the last doesn't. let me know if this is the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess in the dark is when you retrieve the data you use "sender" and not "service" that could explain why the first 2 queries work and the last doesn't.

Let me know if this is the case.

Assuming you are using `JDBC`:

```
    String query = "SELECT sender AS service FROM messages UNION SELECT receiver AS service FROM messages ORDER BY service";
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        String value = rs.getString("sender"); // instead it should be "service"
        // Some other actions
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by his? "sender" and "receiver" are the names in my table. "service" is just an alias I use in the statement with union...

Comment: i mean on code side when you retrieve the data , see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that the problem would be with JDBC and not my statement... I apologize for not providing this information to my question...

Answer (score 1):

It should be this simple because UNION already removes duplicates

```
SELECT sender AS service FROM messages
UNION
SELECT receiver AS service FROM messages
ORDER BY service;
```

The [MySQL docs for UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) agree with this and my sort here

> Instead, provide a column alias in the first SELECT statement and refer to the alias in the ORDER BY

On SQLFiddle my query works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c64e4/7 and does the OPs http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c64e4/8

Comment: I think the point of the question is that the query doesn't work for Smajl for whatever reason

Comment: String query = "SELECT sender AS service FROM messages UNION " +
  "SELECT receiver AS service FROM messages ORDER BY service"; - I have already tried this one, see my question.

Comment: @Smajl: in the question you have brackets. Now, please post *exact* queries please

Comment: @Smajl: check my SQLFiddle link. And your query works too http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c64e4/8

Comment: @gbn I trust you, that the posted query is ok. However, it does not solve my problem. So basically my question would be "Why is it not working for me?"

Comment: My mysql is version 5.6. Could this problem be related to the version?

Comment: How about adding backtick `` to the fieldname?

Answer (score 0):

just delete the `"+"` sign and `"Distinct"` from ur code and try..