# Mysql select distinct multiple columns loop through results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select categories without duplicates from 2 different columns, the table looks something like this:

```
cuisine_1    cuisine_2
----------------------
italian       french
italian       chinese
japanese      german
western
french        german
international
western       sushi
sushi         steak
steak
chinese
vietnamese    chinese
```

Expected result is every category only once where it doesn't matter if it came from `cuisine_1` or `cuisine_2`

I tried like so:

```
$categories=mysqli_query($link,"select distinct cuisine_1,cuisine_2 AS cuisine_unique from table");


while($row_cu=mysqli_fetch_array($categories)){
       echo $row_cu['cuisine_unique']."<br>";
    }
```

Without any luck so far. Do I have to group the results first, or what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: tried to put these two in a single array und use `array_unique()` on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Get unique values across multiple columns in alphabetical order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800980/mysql-get-unique-values-across-multiple-columns-in-alphabetical-order)

Comment: You probably want a union as MamaWalter is suggesting. Distinct will get you distinct rows, not columns. This means that a single column may repeat because all columns in a row have to be unique for the row to be unique which is what you are seeing here. The combination of column 1 and column 2 is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
(SELECT distinct cuisine_1 AS cuisine_unique FROM table) UNION (SELECT distinct cuisine_2 FROM table)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c170d/1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you filter by `cuisine_1` you'll be losing some data from the other column, so you can try by getting one `SELECT DISTINCT` for each column and then merge both arrays and filter by `array_unique`